# Q-GIS Print Composer: underline in HTML (<u>) is almost invisible (too thin)

Tags: qgis, print-composer, html

I am using HTML code to format text in a text box in print composer trying hard to underline just one word of a paragraph. Of course I could create a new text field just for one word but that screws the whole sentence over.

Edit:
 <u>  works fine. As well as ndawsons solution.
The underline is there, it´s just almost invisible. Is there a way to thicken it?

Alternatively a  new bottom border line can be used but that is more of a workaround than a solution:

```
u {
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

*QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa*

Comment: semantically, this example would be correct : http://jsfiddle.net/AQ9rL/

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
 ... <span style="text-decoration: underline">some underlined text</span> ...
```

Comment: I went back to the problem and noticed that both tags produce a very faint line under the text that is almost invisible, updated the question. Thank you.